# Static File Dir django

Tags: django, static, django-staticfiles

ive set my STATIC_ROOT dir in my settings.py. The shell print the path right where the files are located. But on rendering template on /comp/xyz the static files wont be loaded.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/jquery.min.js
```

This is the link rendered by STATIC_URL. its right. But no files.

```
>>> print(settings.STATIC_ROOT)
/home/mandaro/django/comp/static/
>>>
```

there are all my staticfiles. So when i insert {{ STATIC_ROOT }}css/jquery.min.js on my templates. Why is this not working? Any some idea?

Comment: is it the debug webserver? are you using staticfiles_urlpatterns to serve those?

Comment: youp. debug webserver. no staticfiles_urlpatterns. only a STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should really [read the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) about serving static files.

Anyway probably you must add something like this in your urls:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

EDIT:

After your edit I saw that you are using `{{ STATIC_ROOT }}` instead of `{{ STATIC_URL }}` , is that a typo? Also I really advice you to switch to the `{% static %}` template tag, that because it is more portable with different storages.

Comment: i read it yes. but i dont need the media_root. neither i plan to go in production. so i need to learn it first. easy and clean. why is it not working?

Comment: @oranj33 I should point out that only the last line deals with media files

Comment: yes i see though :) and i appreciate it. but whats the reason the files didnt gonna be shown? btw. i gonna try it

Comment: @oranj33 as I said the reason is there in the documentation, in the box titled `Serving the files`